# Python: Getting parent attribute from child attribute in xml

Tags: python-3.x, xml, elementtree, minidom

I have an XML area.xml

```
<area>
<controls>
    <internal>yes</internal>
</controls>
<schools>
    <school id="001"/>
    <time>2020-05-18T14:21:00Z</time>
    <venture index="5">
        <venture>
            <basicData type="class">
                <wage numberOfDollars="13" Correction="4.61">
                    <tax>70</tax>
                </wage>
            </basicData>
        </venture>
    </venture>
    <venture index="9">
        <venture>
            <basicData type="class">
                <wage numberOfDollars="13" Correction="5.61">
                    <tax>70</tax>
                </wage>
            </basicData>
        </venture>
    </venture>
    <school id="056"/>
    <time>2020-05-18T14:21:00Z</time>
    <venture index="5">
        <venture>
            <basicData type="class">
                <wage numberOfDollars="13">
                    <tax>70</tax>
                </wage>
            </basicData>
        </venture>
    </venture>
    <venture index="9">
        <venture>
            <basicData type="class">
                <wage numberOfDollars="13">
                    <tax>70</tax>
                </wage>
            </basicData>
        </venture>
    </venture>
</schools>
```

What i am trying to achieve with Python: in a school node there are multiple wage nodes(leaves). if a wage node(leave)(1 or more) has an attribute called Correction i want the attribute value of the school node.

So the outcome of my script should be: 001 because this school has the attribute Correction in the wage node(leave)

First i tried it using ETree

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data_file = 'area.xml'
tree = ET.parse(data_file)
root = tree.getroot()


t1 = "school"
t2 = "wage"

for e1, e2 in zip(root.iter(t1), root.iter(t2)):
    if hasattr(e2,'Correction'):
        e2.Correction
        print (e1.attrib['id'])
```

but that didn't work. Now I am trying to reach my goal using minidom
but I find it quite hard.

This is my code so far:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse("area.xml")

staffs = doc.getElementsByTagName("wage")
for wage in staffs:
        sid = wage.getAttribute("Correction")

        print("wage:%s" %
              (sid))
```

the output gives all values of the wage attribute Correction:

```
wage:4.61
wage:5.61
wage:
wage:
```

Which is obviously far from correct.

i could use some help getting me in the right direction

i am using python 3

thank you in advance

Comment: the end tag </area> is missing from my xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *in a school node there are multiple wage nodes*

Not really. The `school` elements are empty. The `venture` siblings have the `wage` descendants. Since `wage` is not a descendant of `school`, this makes it a little tricky to select the corresponding `school`.

If you can use [lxml](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html) you could use [XPath](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xpath) to select the `wage` elements that have a `Correction` attribute and then select the first preceding `school` element and get its `id` attribute...

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("area.xml")

schools_with_corrected_wages = set()

for corrected_wage in tree.xpath(".//wage[@Correction]"):
    schools_with_corrected_wages.add(corrected_wage.xpath("preceding::school[1]/@id")[0])

print(schools_with_corrected_wages)
```

This prints:

```
{'001'}
```

You could also use lxml to process the XML with [XSLT](https://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt)...

**XSLT 1.0** (test.xsl)

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="corrected_wage_by_school" match="wage[@Correction]" use="preceding::school[1]/@id"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//school[key('corrected_wage_by_school',@id)]">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(@id,'&#xA;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("area.xml")        
xslt = etree.parse("test.xsl")
result = tree.xslt(xslt)

print(result)
```

This prints...

```
001
```

Comment: I've studied your solution and i understand it and find it very usefull, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a less clever way.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, req, utils
html = utils.getFileContent("area.xml")
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
schools = doc.selects('school') # Get all schools
n = len(schools)
i = 0
while i < n - 1:
    school = schools[i]
    school1 = schools[i + 1]
    h = doc.html[school._end:school1._start] # Get data between two schools
    staffs = doc.getElementsByReg(' Correction="', tag='wage', html=h)
    if staffs:
        print(school.id, staffs.Correction)
    i += 1

last = schools[n - 1]
h = doc.html[last._end:]
staffs = doc.getElementsByReg(' Correction="', tag='wage', html=h)
if staffs:
    print(last.id, staffs.Correction)
```

Result:

```
001 ['4.61', '5.61']
```